# .htaccess RewriteEngine rules for Slim API + AngularJS client

Tags: .htaccess, api, rest, url-rewriting, slim

I am, mostly for learning purposes, building a very simple RESTful API for serving a random image or a specific image given an ID. This API will be accessed via a AngularJS client (probably) and will be deployed, together with the API, to my web server. The API and the web client will reside in the same project, that is the same root folder which will actually be a subdirectory on my server accessible via `http://foo.com/bar` and in the same git repository. Maybe I'll create an Android client later on accessing the same API.

However, I have trouble getting the .htaccess routing/rewriting right. Below follows my proposed directory structure.

```
root/
|-- bar/
|   |-- api/
|   |   |-- v1/
|   |   |   |-- lib/
|   |   |   |   `-- ImageFactory.php
|   |   |   |-- vendor/
|   |   |   |   `-- slim/
|   |   |   |-- .htaccess (#1)
|   |   |   |-- composer.json
|   |   |   `-- index.php
|   |-- public_html/
|   |   |-- css/
|   |   |-- img/
|   |   |   `-- bar/
|   |   |-- js/
|   |   |   |-- controllers/
|   |   |   |-- directives/
|   |   |   |-- filters/
|   |   |   |-- lib/
|   |   |   |-- services/
|   |   |   |-- vendor/
|   |   |   `-- app.js
|   |   |-- views/
|   |   |-- api.php
|   |   `-- index.html
|   `-- .htaccess (#2)
```

I am thinking that each major rework of the API needs a new version which depends on its own version of Slim, should I change the version over the years.

But what about the `.htaccess` files? I think that calls to `http://foo.com/bar` should redirect to `public_html/index.html`, in other words the JS client app. However, calls to `http://foo.com/bar/api/v1` should redirect to `public_html/api.php` and give the version `v1` as a parameter so that `api.php` can load the correct API app.

How should I write my `RewriteEngine` rules for `.htaccess` #1 and #2? Is there something off with my proposed structure? Have I missed something? Please help a developer in need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you only need to add some rules in your `/root/bar/.htaccess` file.

If by `redirect` you mean `internal rewrite` (forward to page without changing url in browser) then you can put this code into your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /bar/

RewriteRule ^$ public_html/index.html [L]
RewriteRule ^api/v([1-9][0-9]*)$ public_html/api.php?version=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I think that did it! What is the purpose of `RewriteBase /bar/`? What does `[L]` do? How are the API "commands", i.e. `api/v1/image/3` magically transferred via `api.php`?

Comment: `RewriteBase /bar/` means all rewrite will begin with `/bar/` in their path, otherwise it won't work. For example, if you try `domain.com/api/v2` it will be rewritten to `/bar/public_html/api.php`. The `L` flag means `Last` and tells the mod-rewrite to leave (other rules below won't be tested). If you try `domain.com/api/v1/image/3` it won't work because the second rule is only matching `domain.com/api/vX`. If you want it to match entire url, tell me and i'll update my answer

Comment: Thing is, I want to use my domain for other projects as well so there may be another API at `foo.com/qux/api`, etc. Should I remove the `RewriteBase` directive then?

Comment: No because you have one specific htaccess per project (your htaccess is in `bar` folder).

Comment: Will there not be a conflict then if `foo.com/api/v1` rewrites to both `foo.com/bar/api/v1` and `foo.com/qux/api/v1` as both directories have `.htaccess` files using `RewriteBase` to their own respective directory?

Comment: You **can't** rewrite to 2 different files. One rule rewrites to one file. Each project you have is represented by a folder at root level (`bar` and `qux` for example). They all have a specific htaccess defining rules for the project only (with its specific `RewriteBase`).

Comment: OK then, I guess I'll cross that bridge then! You are now 50p richer, my Good Sir! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks but i'm mainly glad my answer helped you